# Rounded corner with pseudo element css

Tags: html, css

Please check out the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnr7tqm1/

I have this html markup:

```
    <div class="media-container">
        <iframe width="365" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JqjIb6FhU_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

with the following css:

```
.media-container {
    position: fixed;
    right: 28px;
    bottom: 77px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    iframe {
        margin-left: -16px;
    }
}

.media-container:after, .media-container:before {
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 164px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.media-container:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

.media-container:before {
    border-color: rgba(245, 41, 34, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: 175px;
}
```

I would like to have rounded corners at the bottom of the video too, just like at top. The problem is that i use pseudo element to draw that arrow at the bottom and i have a hard time rounding the bottom corners in this setup.

Anyone has any idea how can this be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding another element and using box-shadows, you can create an "inverse border" the color of the background, masking your video.  See the element ".bottom-borders" below:

```css
.media-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
iframe {
    margin-left: -16px;
}
.media-container:after, .media-container:before {
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 164px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.media-container:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
.media-container:before {
    border-color: rgba(245, 41, 34, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: 175px;
}
.bottom-borders {
    height: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    width: 100%;
}
.bottom-borders:before,
.bottom-borders:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
.bottom-borders:before {
    left: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: -3.5px 3.5px 0 3.5px white;
}
.bottom-borders:after {
    right: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 0 3.5px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-container">
    <iframe width="365" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JqjIb6FhU_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="bottom-borders"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i'm looking for. ;-)

Comment: you could truncate iframe bottom borders : https://jsfiddle.net/xnr7tqm1/3/  `iframe {border-radius: 0 0 10.5% 10.5% /0 0 5em 5em;}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with the shadows for the one pseudoelement and gradients for the another one - no additional real elements needed that way.
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gb8h983r/1/

```
.media-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.media-container iframe {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    margin-left: -5%;
}

.media-container:after, .media-container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.media-container:after {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 16px;
    height: 14px;

    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: -333px 7px #ffffff, 333px 7px #ffffff;
    /* 333px = 340px -7px */
}

.media-container:before {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 16px;

    background:
        linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 49.99%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%) -8px 100%,
        linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 49.99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%) 8px 100%;
    /* 8px = 16px / 2 */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to cover your video by mask image. Something like this:

```css
img {
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    /*right: 28px;
 bottom: 77px;*/
}

.media-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 28px;
    bottom: 77px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg">
<div class="media-container">
    <iframe width="365" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JqjIb6FhU_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
    <div>
```

But imagine that this image is specially drawing PNG, to cover video with 0 opacity.

Comment: Unfortunately many videos contains advertisments that are not allowed to be masked.

Comment: @sc3w I think, you should see how it will be in example. Wait a few minute

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
<div class="fixed">
<div class="media-container">
        <iframe width="340" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JqjIb6FhU_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
      right: 28px;
    bottom: 77px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 200px;
}
.media-container {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    width:340px;
}

.media-container:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

and here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbod8uz6/2/).
This tool is handy, take a [Look](http://cssarrowplease.com/)!

Comment: yeah, this is an easy solution but for UX reasons it's required to have video in the arrow itself too.. :S Thanks anyway.